# how to have the legend inside a grouped bar graph in R ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

So my legend here is village which has (Chirodzo, God, Ruaca). How to remove the legend and display it inside the bars; for instance inside the bar for chirodzo, I want chirodzo written inside?

```
ggplot(data = interviews_plotting, aes(x = respondent_wall_type, fill = village)) +
    geom_bar(position = "fill")
```

Source is here https://mq-software-carpentry.github.io/r-ggplot-extension/02-categorical-data/index.html

```
ggplot(data = interviews_plotting, aes(x = respondent_wall_type, fill = village)) +
    geom_bar(position = "fill")
```

Comment: Could you please share your data? You can use `dput`.

Comment: https://mq-software-carpentry.github.io/r-ggplot-extension/02-categorical-data/index.html

Answer (score 1):

To label your bars with the `fill` category and getting rid of the legend you could use `geom_text` like so:

Using `mtcars` as example data:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = am, fill = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill") +
  geom_text(aes(label = cyl), stat = "count", position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5)) +
  guides(fill = "none")
```

[image]

Comment: So I am using grouped bar charts and not stacked and my text is pretty long and I want it to be displayed vertically and not horizontally, like the angle should be 90

Comment: Hm. Unfortunately the information that you are "using grouped bar charts and not stacked" is not given in your question. You example code and the link you referenced in your comment  is using `position="fill"`, i.e. a stacked barchart. But basically that doesn't matter. The approach is the same. And if you want a solution which is more suitable to your real case then I would suggest to provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data.

Answer (score 1):

From your comments, it sounds like you are looking for something like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(interviews_plotting, aes(x = respondent_wall_type, fill = village)) +
  geom_bar(position = position_dodge()) +
  geom_text(stat = 'count', 
            aes(y = stat(count)/2, label = village, group = village), 
            position = position_dodge(width = 1), angle = 90) +
  guides(fill = guide_none())
```

[image]

Or, if you want to get a bit more sophisticated with your label placement and theme choices:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(interviews_plotting, aes(x = respondent_wall_type, fill = village)) +
  geom_bar(position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), width = 0.8) +
  geom_text(stat = 'count', size = 6,
            aes(y = ifelse(stat(count) > 2, stat(count)/2, stat(count)),
                label = village, group = village, 
                hjust = ifelse(stat(count) > 2, 0.5, -0.2)), 
            position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), angle = 90) +
  labs(x = 'Wall type', y = 'Count') +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = 'Set2', guide = 'none')
```

[image]

---

**Data used**

```r
interviews_plotting <- read.csv(paste0("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/",
                                       "humburg/r-ggplot-project/master/",
                                       "data_output/interviews_plotting.csv"))
```